# Why does read.csv in R convert fields to factors for some files, and not in others?

Tags: r, factors, read.csv

I have tables of weather data from several stations. When I import them separately using read.csv, the fields are factors, integers, and numerics. However, when I try to import one csv file with all of data combined, the resulting fields in a dataframe are all factors. In the combined file the 1st field has several alphanumeric variables, whereas in the individual files there is only one variable (name of station).

Comment: `read.csv('myfile.csv',stringsAsFactors=F)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a commom behaviour of `data.frame()` from `base` R. And most of the times, the result of `read.csv()` will be stored in a `data.frame`. As @Duck suggested in the comment section, you can avoid this behaviour, by setting the `stringsAsFactors` argument to FALSE.

```
read.csv('myfile.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can check this description below on the documentation page of the `data.frame` function. You can access this documentation with `?data.frame` command.

> Character variables passed to data.frame are converted to factor columns unless protected by `I()` or argument `stringsAsFactors` is false.

So in your case, this happens in your combined file, because R are interpreting all variables as caracters. Why? Probably because in one (or some) of your files, in the numeric and integers columns, some lines of data are out of format. For example, maybe in a row, you have an "x" to represent an missing value. And `read.csv()` uses the entire file to decide wich format of data is each column, so as soon as the function hits this "x" value, it interprets the entire column as character. When this data is passed to `data.frame()`, the function converts these characters to factors. You sad that, in the combined file, you have in the first field, some alphanumeric values. So these values, are probably your "x"'s that are generating your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this sill does not explain why it only happens on the combined file, and not the individual files.

Comment: I made an edit, describing what is probably happening in this regard.

Comment: Ahh, that's it! I had some text in the numeric fields toward the bottom of the combined file!

Comment: Great that I help in some way. Do not forget to mark as anwered, if that really fixed your problem.